# Top black bar of the site is glitched

Tags: bug, status-completed

Well as they say, a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

To use Android terminology, the black bar's width is set to `match_parent` rather than `wrap_content`....

**Note:** This happens with both Chrome and Firefox. It was fine this morning...

**Note 2:** Zanna has confirmed she is experiencing this as well

Comment: I can confirm too. Was just wondering whether I should complain anywhere...

Comment: Me too, did not even notice until I saw this.

Comment: FWIW, adding `div.topbar { width: 1090px; margin: 0  auto }` to the site style sheet fixes it (by overriding an incorrect `width: 100%` property). Looks like somebody forgot about Ask Ubuntu's special layout while messing with the top bar CSS. Might have had something to do with preparations for the upcoming [top bar design change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for reporting. It should be fixed now.