# Review queue false negatives on the new top bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, top-bar

I've reviewed several posts regarding the new top bar such as:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357621/review-queue-updates-icon-poll
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355236/the-new-review-icon-isnt-an-improvement
- [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network/300864#300864)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343100/the-link-for-review-queue-is-broken

but none of these seem to address my particular case. While working on https://askubuntu.com/, after entering the review queue, the review light went out and stayed out even though there were many incomplete reviews and I had left the review queue.

Here's the evidence:

[image: reviewqueueunlit]

[image: closevotestoreview]

Don't get me wrong, I'm sure I can adjust to the change, but I'm concerned that this bug will result in reviews going unaccomplished.

**Edit:** Although it currently doesn't seem to address our "office supply threat level" (quoting @Zanna comment [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17346/review-queue-false-negatives-on-the-new-top-bar?noredirect=1#comment35937_17346), [Makyen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/271271/makyen) has developed a script that will customize the new top nav bar that looks like it may resolve many of the complaints regarding it in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301909/260418) to [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live)

Note: I haven't yet tested it as I'm still holding out hope for something that will actually provide review count.

Comment: the presence/non-presence of the dot seems to be random. How are we to know the office supply threat level?

Comment: @Zanna "office supply threat level"...LOL. Pray tell what that means, ie someone is taking too many pens home? Running low on yellow sticky notes? ps the only reason I'm here is the new top bar is godawful and was curious if anyone else felt the same.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17290/vote-do-you-like-the-new-top-bar-design :) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355236/the-new-review-icon-isnt-an-improvement

Answer (score -2):

After you click the review icon (or visit the review queues), we don't highlight the icon for a while (I believe up to an hour) - you have noticed it and we don't want it to feel like it is nagging, in particular once you have already taken action.

Comment: I personally would consider differentiating between clicking on the icon and and a queue and actually reviewing a post. be that as it may, as @Zanna alluded to in  this [comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17346/review-queue-false-negatives-on-the-new-top-bar/17347#comment35902_17346) we can no longer see what the backlog is. I for one am  perfectly capable of ignoring nagging, but it's nice to know when the grass is over a foot high and needs immediate attention if you catch my meaning. :-)

Comment: I think this is actually helpful (or more helpful than red dot on if there's anything whatever available I can review, which on Ask Ubuntu will always be the case, except for about 10 seconds after I've reviewed absolutely everything), because in the absence of text, it reminds me I need to do something (buy staples? oh no, review, right) I haven't done for a while

Comment: Can this be expanded to give (or link to) specific timings? *Is* it "up to an hour," and if so, what does that mean, exactly? Right now, speaking for myself but also for what I think is the tone of people's reactions: the highlighting is obscure, confusing, alienating. But this might be mitigated if, when users are confused about why it works the way it does and we check here on meta for a bug report, we quickly and easily find a clear, *complete* description--or a link to such a description--of *what* is happening. This won't make us like the top bar, but it would be helpful. At least to me.

Comment: @EliahKagan We will get a full explanation of how the review queue indicator works up in the next week or so. There are ways that CoGro can tune the system for smaller sights to work better and we'll explain those. We are also open to making improvements.