# New navbar bug review queues not operating as expected

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, top-bar

This is different from [Review queue false negatives on the new top bar](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17346/review-queue-false-negatives-on-the-new-top-bar) which has been dismissed as status-by-design. When I first logged on this morning the review queue indicator was not lit. After donating my time here for almost 4 years, I was certain that that was false. So I clicked on it to see if any of the queues showed anything and got this:

[image]

Clicking on the unindicated <kbd>Close Votes</kbd> resulted in the the Close vote candidate shown in the picture above.

Further digging indicated that many of the queues should have triggered some response as seen here after immediately clicking <kbd>all queues</kbd>:

[image: LoadedQueues]

I seriously can't believe that this is by design, and if it is, I would respectfully request reconsideration as this is not only useless, but causes harm by projecting the false indication that there are no queues to work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I was wrong and the new behaviour is intentional. It's not so much the fault of the new topbar itself, but rather an attempt to draw attention to review in different ways at around the same time.

Shog9 posted a bit more about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red/355234#355234), but basically current implementation is designed to add a red dot to the icon when any of the queues are in a "danger zone". The thresholds for that can be configured per site and on AU the values at the moment are as follows:

- Close Votes: 200
- First Posts: 30
- Late Answers: 30
- Low Quality: 20
- Reopen Votes: 10
- Suggested Edits: 10

We're still monitoring review to see whether this indicator continues to perform well or if any other changes are needed.